# How to prove this divisibility?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given 3 | $(a^2+b^2)$. Show that 9 | $(a^2+b^2)$ 
I was given only examples, but not a rigorous proof. No clue how to do it, even using contradiction method. Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

1. $a^2 \equiv 0$ or $1 \pmod{3}$. Same for $b^2$, so there are four cases total. When is $a^2 + b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$?
2. If $3 \mid a^2$, $9 \mid a^2$. Same for $b^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For any integer $n, n\equiv0,1,2\pmod3\implies n^2\equiv0,1\pmod3$

$$ a^2+ b^2\equiv0+0,0+1,1+0,1+1\pmod3$$